# Stop concurrent multiple client's access to the ASP.NET Web API and ASP.NET Identity 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, token

**Problem statement:**

Hi. I have some secured data which I want to expose through Web API and ASP.NET Identity mechanism. I want to use out of the box classes of ASP.NET Identity. I take a payment manually and change a value in the table. But there are cases where the user will share his username + password with some other guys so that the others can access the same content without paying anything.

**Work plan:**

So, I have extended the AspNetUsers table with a column named ApplicationToken (varchar). After successful login, I want to generate a token, update the field of the user's row in the table, and add this value as a claim information and send back to the client app. Now, when the user requests for a paid content, my client app will send the token also. So, somewhere in my server side codes, I need to check this ApplicationToken with the Database token value. If both are equal, I allow the request to proceed, otherwise I will send 401 Unauthorized and tell them to login again.

**Implementation options:**

After studying  and searching, I found the below options to implement:

1. Create Custom Authentication Filter attribute so that I can grab the claims send from the client and do my required validation
2. Create a base class of the secured API and get the claims there and do my required validation.
3. Go for different Jwt based implementation where I should have access in both issuing and checking the Json Web Tokens.

If you have any other options, I would be very glad to hear those.

***My question is, which approach is better to proceed. I have enough time to implement, so time is not a factor here. Thanks.***

Comment: How about two-factor? They may share username/password, but if original user has to keep telling people the code s/he gets they may shy away from sharing it.

Comment: i need to stop it. two factor is good, but not appropriate for my case. those who do the piracy doesn't have any ethics.

Comment: Is the content something you can limit?  E.g only 3 views available per purchase?

Comment: At the end of the day, you're not going to get far. Ask the MPAA how music and video piracy counter measures are going. If you limit concurrent users, people will just download it and share it offline. Either consider a new pricing model or consider it a cost of business. (Consider how music went from $15/20 a CD to $.99 a song and the impact on how frequently it was pirated).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion @Brad. You are absolutely right and mine are videos. 
But I believe I should restrict it as much as possible. I will keep you updated here.